# $_GET not working in code, working before upgrading to PHP7

Tags: php-7

This the code, I keep getting the error function not define but Im attempting to retrieve the data from mysql. This code was working with an older version on PHP.

```
$date1 = $_GET['date1'];
$date2 = $_GET['date2'];

if (validateDate($date1){
    $date1status = true;
} else {
    $date1status = false;
}

if (validateDate($date2){
    $date2status = true;
} else {
    $date2status = false;
}

$bywho = $_GET['bywho'];
if (!empty($bywho) {
    $whostatus = true;
} else {
    $whostatus = false;
}

$programfilter = $_GET['programfilter'];

if ($programfilter == '') {
    $programfilterstatus = false;
} else {
    $programfilterstatus = true;
}
```

Comment: I think you missed an important bit of information, the actual and complete error message. Please [edit] your question to add it and the `validateDate` function which appears to be the only function being called in what you posted so far.

Comment: DUH **function not define** So where is the FUNCTION `validateDate()` defined ??

Answer (score 0):

Less code

```
$date1status=validateDate( $_GET['date1']) ?  true :false;

$date2status=$date2 =validateDate( $_GET['date2']) ?  true :false;

$whostatus=$_GET['bywho']   ? true : false;

$programfilter = $_GET['programfilter'] ?  true :false;
```

Comment: ..but not exactly the same. Also.. not an answer.

Comment: I can see validateDate function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume your validateDate() method is not defined, and since its not part of the PHP library, you're getting the error.

checkdate() is part of the php library however. If you're just trying to validate a date in gregorian format then checkdate() is what you should use

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

```
$date1 = $_GET['date1'];
$date2 = $_GET['date2'];

if (checkdate($date1){
    $date1status = true;
} else {
    $date1status = false;
}

if (checkdate($date2){
    $date2status = true;
} else {
    $date2status = false;
}

$bywho = $_GET['bywho'];
if (!empty($bywho) {
    $whostatus = true;
} else {
    $whostatus = false;
}

$programfilter = $_GET['programfilter'];

if ($programfilter == '') {
    $programfilterstatus = false;
} else {
    $programfilterstatus = true;
}
```

Comment: @Greanny Santos did this help you at all?